# Dynamic Projection in linq with List of fieldNames

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, dynamic-linq

I wanna do projection on fields of my collection and nested collection in each of entity,
I use EntityFramework 6.2
I've do that  with dynamic query like bellow code

```
Students.Select("new (Name,Family,new(Category.Name) as Category)");
```

it was worked but when I want to do that on the collection it's thrown error

```
  Students.Select("new (Name,Family,new(Courses.Name,Courses.UnitName) as Courses)");
```

I want,it returns result as bellow code returns

```
Students.Select(std=>new{
 std.Name, 
 Category=new{std.Category.Name},
 Courses=std.Courses.Select(co=>new{
  co.Name,co.UnitName
})}) ;
```

please if you have any idea share with me

Comment: You are using one of the many Dynamic Linq libraries. Which one?

Comment: @xanatos I used System.Linq.Dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with [`System.Linq.Dynamic`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/). It is possible with [`System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) (a more advanced fork of the library).

Equivalent to the query you wrote in non-dynamic way:

```
var q = Students.Select("new (Name, Category.Name as Category, Courses.Select(new (Name, UnitName)) as Courses)");
```

What you were looking for is simply `Courses.Select(new (field1, field2)) as SomeAlias`

Comment: it doesn't work,it's thrown error 'No applicable aggregate method 'Select' exists'

Comment: @MasoudMirzaei Works on my PC with latest https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/

Comment: I check it again,I used exact new version but it doesn't work,I created a new clear project and test it again but it doesn't work also,it 's throw the same error

Comment: I appreciate you dear xanatos.it works but I see in your code I must use system.linq.dynamic.core instead of system.linq.dynamic

Comment: @MasoudMirzaei Ah yes... hadn't noticed... I was reusing an old solution that uses `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` (that is a maintained version of `System.Linq.Dynamic`). With the "original" `System.Linq.Dynamic` there is no support for what you are trying to do.